# No overload for method 'DownloadFile' takes '2' arguments. Чего не хватает?

Tags: c#, ftp

Функция `DownloadFile()` требует 3 аргумента, но абсолютно везде в интернете используется 2.
И когда я тоже использую 2 агрумента, то выдается такая ошибка: `No overload for method 'DownloadFile' takes '2' arguments`.

Вот пример использования: [ссылка](http://www.csidata.com/?page_id=2828)

Вот мой код:

```
using (var sftp = new SftpClient(Host, Port, Username, Password))
{
    sftp.Connect();
    using (var file = File.OpenWrite(LocalDestinationFilename))
    {
        sftp.DownloadFile(RemoteFileName, file); //ошибкатут
    }
   sftp.Disconnect();
}
```

Comment: В библиотеке вот это 
 public void DownloadFile(string path, Stream output, Action<ulong> downloadCallback);

Comment: А какую версию используете? В [библиотеке](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Renci.SshClient/Renci.SshNet/SftpClient.cs) вот это: `public void DownloadFile(string path, Stream output, Action<ulong> downloadCallback = null)` Т.е. должно и с двумя пускать

Comment: Случаем, не на Visual Studio 2008 программируете? Все что древнее VS 2010 не понимает опциональные параметры.

Comment: попробуйте написать вместо 3его параметра null xD